# CSS placing images side by side - I don't want them side by side

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble with html/css image alignment.

I had a html page with lots of text and two images held in figure markup and figcaption tags.

When I apply the following CSS to it it makes by images side-by-side and messes up the whole flow of the page..

```
img {
  float:right;
  margin:0px 0px 10px 10px;
}
```

Below is my html with the text cut short for space saving on here:

```
<figure>
  <img src="http-message.gif" alt="A di">
  <figcaption>Figur</figcaption>
</figure>

<p>The HTTP request message is route</p>  

<figure>
  <img src="www-diagram.gif" alt="A diagram">
  <figcaption>Figure 2. (1) The HTTP Req
</figcaption>
</figure>
```

```css
img {
  float: right;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Scqxm.png?s=64&g=1" alt="A di">
  <figcaption>Figur</figcaption>
</figure>

<p>The HTTP request message is route</p>

<figure>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Scqxm.png?s=64&g=1" alt="A diagram">
  <figcaption>Figure 2. (1) The HTTP Req</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Can anybody help me make sure the images flow down the page as intended?

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you add jsfiddle example?

Comment: Would probably make more sense to float the figure elements instead of the img.

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate of the question that has been linked. I have the opposite problem

Answer (score 1):

here is the sample **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ceg550j2/1/)**

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
img{
  max-width: 120px;
}
figure{
  text-align: center;
}
p{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<figure>
 <img src="http://smalldata.io/startup/common-files/icons/sdl_logo.png" alt="A di">
 <figcaption>Figur caption</figcaption>
</figure>

<figure>
 <img src="https://sixpillarstopersia.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/fb_logo1.png" alt="A diagram">
 <figcaption>Figure 2. (1) The HTTP Req
</figcaption>
</figure>
<p>The HTTP request message is route</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This works a little but not as I intended. I'm new to this site and can't work out how to insert an image here. But basically this places my paragraph of text in between the two images when I need it to wrap around the first image.

Comment: @PJGannon What's the issue?

Comment: Sorry accidentally posted the comment before finished - edited now.